# What does the '@' mean in front of the repo name in `dnf list`?

Tags: fedora, package-management, repository, dnf

When I want to list installed packages, I do it usually in one of two ways.

The old fashioned way is using `rpm -qa | grep <whatever I look for>`, and that's that.

But recently I wanted a more comprehensive display of my packages, and henceforth, I used `dnf list --installed <whatever I look for>`.

However when looking at the result there are a couple things I don't understand.

Consider this example:

```
# dnf list --installed zsh                  
Last metadata expiration check: 0:13:25 ago on Mon Jul 11 05:48:04 2016.
Installed Packages
zsh.x86_64            5.2-5.fc24            @@commandline
```

*(spaces in actual printout are wider)*

So the resulting entries, are: «package» «version» «repo».

In my example that's:

- package: zsh.x86_64
- version: 5.2-5.fc24
- repo: @@commandline

So far the resulting table is understandable, but I'm confused what the two '@@' mean in front of the repo name.

Also, "commandline" suggests the package was installed from command line (downloading the RPM, and then doing `dnf install whatever.rpm` *in the command line*, etc.). However I'm pretty sure I've installed `zsh` via `dnf install zsh`.

But that's not all.

I've several packages on my system installed from the repo `@System`, `@fedora` (however there's also `fedora` without the `@`) and things like `@@commandline`.

So what does that `@` or `@@` exactly mean in front of the repo name?

And how come I've got so many prominent packages installed from `@@commandline` although I'm more than sure I've installed them from the repos?

Answer (score 4):

Let me throw a brick to attract some jade here.

`dnf list all | less` shows all packages(including installed and available packages). The output has two sections: "Installed Packages" and "Available Packages". All "Installed Packages" are preceded by @ sign, while "Available Packages" are not. So I believe `@` signs show the packages are installed. If a package is installed but its original repo was deleted, I guess `@@` sign is given.

dnf source code is hosted at https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf. After downloading the src code, do a `grep commandline -ri .` in the directory and it returns nothing. However, its github page does mention this,

> It does package management using RPM, libsolv and hawkey libraries.

So I look at hawkey, which is hosted under same project, at https://github.com/rpm-software-management/hawkey. Looking at its code by `grep -ri commandline .`, it does show some results.

```
./src/types.h:#define HY_CMDLINE_REPO_NAME "@commandline"
./hawkey.spec:- fix: commandline RPMs do not provide their files (RhBug:1112810) (Ales Kozumplik)
```

So `commandline` comes from `hawkey` package. As to question why `@comandline` is shown in `dnf list` command, my wild guess is `dnf` code fails to use `hawkey` properly.

Comment: It seems the man page of `dnf` is incredibly silent about this. Suppose '@' denotes an installed package, does '@@' then mean it's manually installed from a non-repo source, perhaps? I'd really wish someone would clarify.

Comment: "Let me throw a brick to attract some jade here." ...I have absolutely no idea what that awesome and incomprehensible expression means, and I think I love it.  ["Idioms!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mY9gVIcRkkI)

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I can't provide sources for any of this, because I've never seen any documentation which actually discusses these things. The information to follow is merely what I've been able to suss out through inspection, blackbox experimentation, haphazard trial-and-error, and plain old guesswork. Also, fair warning, it's overexpository to the point of being *waaaay* too long.)

DNF adds an @ to denote the repo an *installed* package was installed **from**, in `dnf list` context. As you noted:

> I've several packages on my system installed from the repo @System, @fedora (however there's also fedora without the @) and things like @@commandline.

But in reality, you'll never see any package coming from `fedora` on the *installed* list, as every package there shows some @-repo as its source. (You can verify that by running `sudo dnf list installed` and inspecting; there are no repos listed without at least one @ sign.) When you view a  package's information with `dnf info`, the "`From repo:`" field will show that repo name without the `@`. (So "`From repo: fedora`" is absolutely possible, and equivalent to `@fedora` in the installed list.)

But some repos are *named* with an `@` sign at the front. As JohnKoch discovered in the hawkey sources, "@commandline" is defined as the "repo name" for "the commandline repo". So, `@@commandline` in the `dnf list` listing simply indicates an installed package `From repo: @commandline`, a repo which confusingly was given a name that starts with its own @-sign.

`dnf info` on any installed package will show `Repository: @System`, which is the other `@`-named virtual repo. It seems that `@System` is the virtual repo that holds the set of currently-installed packages, and `@commandline` the virtual *source repo* from whence a package came, when it did not come from any repo.

The meaning of `@commandline` and `@System`, and their relationship to each other, seems to have changed since I first wrote this answer. In some ways it's more consistent, and addresses some of my previous objections about how `@commandline` is used. I no longer see *any* installed packages listed as being from `@@System`, and out-of-band installs will indeed now show `From repo: @commandline` (`@@commandline` in list context). `dnf info` on an out-of-band installed package typically shows something like the following:

```
$ dnf info remi-release
Installed Packages
Name         : remi-release
---✀---
Repository   : @System
From repo    : @commandline
```

If I do a `dnf reinstall remi-release` (because the package **is** in the `remi` repo), it changes to:

```
$ dnf info remi-release
Installed Packages
Name         : remi-release
---✀---
Repository   : @System
From repo    : remi
```

##### Update post-2020 changes

A package's source repo *used to* depend on the repo existing in the current package database, but that's thankfully changed. DNF now [queries its history database](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/blob/259e4c9d675a8c2faaeceee8aee3527e5d25ec9f/dnf/package.py#L82-L94), rather than the current set of package repos, for information on installed packages. So, the name of the source repo is now preserved even across system upgrades.

##### Previous, now-outdated info

One other thing about source repos: The repos listed in the `From repo:` field are always repos that exist *in the current repo context*. In other words, a package's installation source isn't merely a string containing the repo name; installed packages are linked to the **identity** of the providing repo as it exists (or existed) in the system.

Since most repos are distro-versioned, they get redefined with each new Fedora release. (As e.g. the "`fedora`" repo becomes the set of packages that make up the new release, a completely different repo from the "`fedora`" that existed under the previous release.) So, whenever a system-upgrade is done, lots of old repo identities get invalidated.

DNF (or hawkey) used to relegate packages installed from repos that no longer exist to `@commandline` as their source repo. I say "used to", because that is (thankfully) no longer done. Installed packages that came from a repo that no longer exists will no longer show their source as `@@commandline` / `From repo: @commandline`. In fact, `dnf info` shows that they no longer have *any* source repo. For example, `sitecopy` was a Fedora package that's since been retired. I installed it from the `fedora` or `updates` repo 7 or 8 releases ago, and still have it installed:

```
$ dnf info sitecopy
Installed Packages
Name         : sitecopy
Version      : 0.16.6
Release      : 14.fc22
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 373 k
Source       : sitecopy-0.16.6-14.fc22.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
```

There is no "`From repo:`" listed.

This does confusingly mean that `dnf list installed` will show *that* package (and others like it) with `@System` (one `@`) listed next to it. So in a sense we've just traded one inconsistency for another, as that column is no longer always the source repo with `@` prepended. Still, I prefer the current state of affairs.

#### Footnotes

1. "...the one that's shown..."
   (Sometimes shown. "Available Packages" won't necessarily show up on
   every `dnf list` run: If the installed version of a package is the
   best available version, it's listed under "Installed Packages" so it
   would be redundant to also list it under "Available Packages". Using
   `--showduplicates` will force an "Available Packages" section which
   includes all known instances, regardless of version, whether
   installed or downloadable.)

Comment: I've updated this answer with some observed changes in F30 compared to F28 (when it was originally written), and also to address the things raised at [this duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515325/understanding-the-meaning-of-in-package-management).