# Understanding the meaning of @ in package management

Tags: fedora, package-management, repository, dnf

I discovered `tmux` is installed on my system. In order to find out if it was preinstalled with fedora I ran the command `dnf info tmux` which prints out:

```
Installed Packages
Name         : tmux
Version      : 2.7
Release      : 1.fc28
Arch         : x86_64
Size         : 765 k
Source       : tmux-2.7-1.fc28.src.rpm
Repo         : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : A terminal multiplexer
URL          : https://tmux.github.io/
License      : ISC and BSD
Description  : tmux is a "terminal multiplexer."  It enables a number of terminals (or
             : windows) to be accessed and controlled                     from a single terminal.  tmux is
             : intended to be a simple, modern, BSD-licensed alternative to programs such
             : as GNU Screen.
```

Based on the above output it seems that `@` means "at" so
`Repo: @System` means "at system" (i.e. the package is not in a repository instead the package is installed at the system) or in other words (package `tmux` is) installed at the system.

However tracking down the transaction when `tmux` was installed with `dnf history list tmux` (which showed something like transaction ID 55), and `dnf history list 55` the following line is part of the resulting output:

```
Install    tmux-2.7-1.fc28.x86_64               @updates
```

#### Based on the above findings which of the following understanding of `@` in package management is correct?

- The line above makes it clear that `tmux` was installed from the updates repository but assuming that `@` means "at" shouldn't that mean installed at the updates repository? In other words, why does `@` in the output of `dnf info <packagename>` mean "at" e.g. `@System` means "at System", but in the output of `dnf history list 55`, `@` seems to mean "from"?
- Alternatively does `@` mean "install the package `tmux-2.7-1.fc28.x86_64` at the repository `@updates`", or in other words, "install the package `tmux-2.7-1.fc28.x86_64` that is at the repository `updates`"? Which makes sense given that the line below from the same output should read as: upgraded `subversion` at the repository `fedora/27`.

```
Upgraded   subversion-1.9.7-1.fc27.x86_64       @fedora/27
```

**Edit:** My question is not a duplicate. Where as the other question is asking what `@` means, this question is different in that I researched/investigated the meaning of `@` in the package manager after which I posted a question to confirm which of my understanding of the results of the research/investigation is correct. Besides the answers to the [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295063/what-does-the-mean-in-front-of-the-repo-name-in-dnf-list) question are low quality. For example the first answer makes the following statement:

> All "Installed Packages" are preceded by `@` sign, while "Available Packages" are not. So I believe `@` signs show the packages are installed.

This is not correct because for example with that flawed answer

```
Install    tmux-2.7-1.fc28.x86_64         @updates
```

would mean that `tmux` is already installed which it is not. So that rules out `@` meaning that a package is already installed

and the second answer states:

> DNF uses `@` to denote the repo an installed package was installed from. As you noted

That's wrong because then `@System` would mean that the package was installed from your system.  My understanding of `@` in the main question shows why this quote from the second answer to the other question is wrong.

Comment: »» find out if it was preinstalled with fedora «« : You can create a list with install dates → `$ rpm -qa --last > installed-packages.txt`. ... Besides that, "releases" has `tmux` included https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/28/Workstation/x86_64/os/Packages/t/

Comment: @MichaelHampton , see my edit for why this question is not a duplicate

Comment: @KnudLarsen , that link to the fedora 28 releases is useful because it confirms that tmux is included in the fedora 28 upgrade/installation. As for the rpm command you provided, how is it different to `dnf list --installed`?

Comment: »» ... the rpm command you provided, how is it different to dnf list --installed? «« : Why not do both commands yourself ? .... `rpm -qa --last > last-packages.txt` writes a list ordered by date, the latest install at line 1 : Very useful. ... `dnf list --installed > dnf-list.txt` writes an alphabetic list. No dates. ... Quite different !

Comment: See [How to differentiate between repo and built packages with dnf?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457286/how-to-differentiate-between-repo-and-built-packages-with-dnf/457287#457287)

Comment: @JRFerguson , appreciate the link.  It is useful

Comment: I'm just curious why you would post this as a new question, instead of posting comments to the other question/answers and _engaging_ with the "low quality" answers in a way that allows everyone to benefit from it. This question is absolutely a duplicate, the fact that it refers to the answers on the other question proves it. A _separate_ "follow-up question" is not a thing here. The other question/answers can, should (and despite your fracturing, will)
 be enhanced.

Comment: (That being said, the close-reason message leaves a lot to be desired, and that's on StackExchange. "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question." That's just a terrible way to put it, and sounds borderline contradictory.)